# My while loop accepts answers it shouldn't. Why?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a while loop that isn't working correctly and cannot find the problem.  I can enter a "L", for example and it doesn't initiate the loop.  Does anyone see my problem?

```
<script>
var wood = prompt("Enter wood type (M)ahogany, (O)ak, (P)ine");
    while (wood != "M" && wood != "m" && wood != "O" && wood != "o" && wood != "P" && wood != "p" && wood == "")
    {
        wood = prompt("invalid wood please enter (M)ahogany, (O)ak, (P)ine ");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the answer above said, you need to change the empty string to an "OR" instead of "AND"

However, I would probably write it a little more readable like

```
let woods = ['M','O','P'];
while (!wood || !woods.includes(wood.toUpperCase()))
```

This way you don't need to chain a bunch of different variations. Just put it once in the array and make anything that is in the input as uppercase.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`&& wood == ""` ... is only true if `wood` is empty, so the only value that passes in your condition is an empty string.

You could change it to

```
while ((wood != "M" && wood != "m" && wood != "O" && wood != "o" && wood != "P" && wood != "p") || (wood == "")) { ...
```

or simplify it by using `String.includes`

```
var woods = "MOP";
var wood  = prompt("Enter wood type (M)ahogany, (O)ak, (P)ine");

while (!( wood && woods.includes(wood.toUpperCase()) )) {
  wood = prompt("invalid wood please enter (M)ahogany, (O)ak, (P)ine ");
}
```